# Where does Bibdesk store its preferences files?

Tags: mac, bibdesk

I would like to set up BibDesk on a new computer running Mac OS 10.15.4, using all the same preferences, settings, templates, cite-key generation instructions, etc. as on my old computer running Mac OS 10.14.6.

I have migrated the file `~/Library/Preferences/edu.ucsd.cs.mmccrack.bibdesk.plist` and the directory `~/Library/Application Support/BibDesk/`, but BibDesk does not seem to have gotten the memo.

What files do I still need to transfer, and where do they live?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

macOS caches the preferences in memory with first use and will overwrite the one you put in place. Immediately after putting the file in place run

`defaults read ~/Library/Preferences/edu.ucsd.cs.mmccrack.bibdesk.plist`

in Terminal). Hope that helps